# combination of 2 classes

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

## Create separate data generators for training and validation

train_data = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
train_path,
target_size=(img_size,img_size),
batch_size=batch_size_train,
class_mode='categorical',
classes=['AKIEC et BCC','VASC et DF','MEL & NV & BKL']
)

Found 0 images belonging to 3 classes.